# Random Dice Roll Game in Python

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop, dice

So I have looked at all related questions and can't seem to find answers specific to my program. I have to have two player dice game that rolls a random number and declares the winner. As of now, when the program runs it says: 
The winner is:
Enter player 1 name:
Enter player 2 name:

Here is my code:

```
import random

def main():
    print "You are now playing Dice Roll!!"

endProgram = 'no'
playerOne = 'NO NAME'
playerTwo = 'NO NAME'

playerOne, playerTwo = inputNames(playerOne, playerTwo)

while endProgram == 'no':
    winnnerName = 'NO NAME'
    p1number = '0'
    p2number = '0'

    playerOne,playerTwo = inputNames(playerOne,playerTwo)
    winnerName =()

winnerName = rollDice(p1number, p2number, playerOne, playerTwo, winnerName)

displayInfo = winnerName


endProgram = raw_input('Do you want to end program? (Enter yes or no): ')

def inputNames(playerOne,playerTwo):
    playerOne = raw_input('Enter player one name:')
    playerTwo = raw_input('Enter player two name:')
    return playerOne, playerTwo


def rollDice(p1number, p2number, playerOne, playerTwo, winnerName):
    p1number = random.randint(1,6)
    p2number = random.randint(1,6)

if p1number == p2number:
    print "TIE!!!!"
elif p1number > p2number:
    print winnnerName
else:
    p1number < p2number
    print winnnerName

return winnerName

print "The winner is:",winnerName

main()
```

I'm not looking for the answer just the guidance to go be on the right path.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some steps that should help and guide you :

## Coding

1. Be sure to indent your code correctly, as this is part of the python syntax. So lines with `def ...():` should not be indented, definitions content should be indented of one level, `while` content should be indented of two levels... And so on. So you should only have `import` and the different `def` aligned on the left (Maybe it happened when you pasted your code on stackoverflow, but just to be sure).
2. Stop passing arguments to every definition you make. If you do not need to pass a variable value to a function, don't use arguments. For instance, in `def inputNames(playerOne,playerTwo)`, arguments `playerOne,playerTwo` are useless because you're just using this function to define their value. The same problem appears in `rollDice`.
3. Be careful about typos, you wrote "winnnerName" with 3 "n" in rollDice.
4. Keep it simple. Use only what is needed. Your code is well structured. But these functions should do only what they are intended to do. Example : `rollDice` should only roll dices, and not announce the result. So you may just return the winner, or even return the numbers and test the winner in the main program. That bring us to the next part, the algorithm.

## Algorithm

A good practice if you aren't comfortable with your code, is to write down your algorithm. It will be much clearer.
So you should basically end up with something like this :

1. **main function :** the one called once when starting the program

   - Welcomes user
   - Sets useful variables : endProgram (we need it later to enter the loop)
   - Calling inputNames -> we store the players names, only once at the beginning except if you want players to be able to change them
   - Then enter the loop executed as long as user doesn't end program :
   - Calling rollDice -> we can store the 2 dices numbers returned by rollDice, test which player is the winner, and directly output which winner won **OR** test which player won in rollDice which return the player name, and print it if not tie.
   - Finally ask the player if he wants to stop the game, and store his response in endProgram.
   - End of the loop
2. **inputNames :** called to ask players names

   - Input name of player 1 and store it
   - Input name of player 2 and store it
   - Return stored players names
3. **rollDice :** called to get random numbers

   - Generate and store random number for player 1
   - Generate and store random number for player 2
   - Return the stored random numbers
4. (3bis) **rollDice alternative :** called to get winner's name. Here you need to pass players names in argument

   - Generate and store random number for player 1
   - Generate and store random number for player 2
   - Set winner name to 'NO NAME' in case it's tie
   - Test which player won, modifying winner name if not tie
   - Return the winner name

Now you can try yourself, you can certainly enhance it.
Here is one I made, you can use it for reference if you get stuck : https://repl.it/BiKd/6.

Comment: Yea, the arguments seemed to be holding me back a good bit. I got lost reading where they needed to be, and where I actually had them. You cleared up a whole lot of confusion for me. I'm gonna go fix my code now!!!! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome ! By the way, I also corrected something else. You were first testing for the variable `winnerName == "NO NAME"`, but let's pretend a player used this as a player name. Every time he wins it'll say it's tie. So I defined it as `winnerName = None` and tested it with `winnerName is None`.